# Brand new Standalone Angular project failing on Visual Studio 2022 preview

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022

I just choose standalone angular project from the templates, after I give it a name, set the location and press create it gives me this.

I checked the visual studio installer but it doesn't show the Javascript SDK as an option. I am trying to see if I can install it globally using Nugget but it seems a desperate attempt to work around something that is just ridiculously basic...

I still hope one day I can develop angular projects on Visual Studio 20** with dignity... let's see.

[image]

Comment: You can try to repair Visual Studio 2022 and install your missing SDK. Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIe38G0nINY

Comment: I did that that, I also repaired .net 6.0 but still the same error. I am giving up now and returning to vscode but I hope one day we can have a decent angular environment in vs 20## without having to have asp.net with it